# When adding more text into a RichTextBox and highlighting, it clears all previous highlights

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I'm making a debug/log form that saves all the things done in the others forms at the specific time: like pressing a button, entering some info in textbox, etc.

In every line I highlight the actual time that corresponds to the same day, for example, today is 10/08/2019 so:

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeVKy.jpg)

10/08/2019 corresponds to the actual date, so it's highlighted. The problem is that when I do another thing like pressing L button it shows like this:

[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tyr8g.jpg)

Below I put the code that it interprets this:
CMD = RichTextBox

```
private void ChequearDatos()
{
    string line = CMD.Text;
    int x = xk, xx = 0, lent = 0;
    lent = line.Length;

    do
    {
        else if (line[x] == '\n')
        {
            xk = x;                   
            x++;
        }

        else if (line[x] == '■')
        {
            xx = x + 1;
            do
            {
                xx = xx + 1;
            }
            while (line[xx] != '=');
            string pedazo = line.Substring(x + 2, (xx - x) - 12);
            if (pedazo == Convert.ToString(DateTime.Today.Day + "/" + DateTime.Today.Month + "/" + DateTime.Today.Year))
            {
                CMD.SelectionStart = x;
                CMD.SelectionLength = xx - x + 1;
                CMD.SelectionColor = System.Drawing.Color.OrangeRed;
            }
            else
            {
                CMD.SelectionStart = x;
                CMD.SelectionLength = xx - x + 1;
                CMD.SelectionColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkKhaki;
            }
            CMD.SelectionStart = CMD.TextLength;

            CMD.ScrollToCaret();
            if (xx + 1 > lent) { break; }
            else { x = xx + 1; } 
        }
        else { x = x + 1; }
    }
    while (x <= lent - 1);
}
```

The program search for ■ and =, the inside of it if it's the same date it will be highlighted with DarkKhaki colour, if not, it will be highlighted with OrangeRed colour.

In the first run, it runs good, but when I add more text and call that function again it highlight everything in white except the last message.

> Edit: I tried without saving the **xk** int variable, but when I call this function the program needs to process all the text again and starts to blink until checked all of it.

Comment: I would suggest that you reconsider how you do this. Instead of highlighting the text by processing all the text after you append a line, format the line as you append it.

Comment: Are you sure that there is no spot in the code you don't show that changes the rtb.Text? The result looks a lot as if that is the case..

Comment: @TaW I only changes the rtb.text when I do something in another form, after that i call this function to highlight the day, but this problems occurs.

Comment: _I ..change the rtb.text in another form_ Well that will usually mess up previous formatting.So does the issue come up when calling the function twice without changing the text in between? How do you change the text? Can you show the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it appending it like @TnTinMin said, before I call this function another function writes in the RTB as below:

```
void PrintRTB(string a)
{
  RTB.text += "■ " +  a + "\n";
  ChequearDatos();
}
```

Now I use the command [.appendtext] and works!

```
void PrintRTB(string a)
{
  RTB.AppendText("■ " + a + "\n");
  ChequearDatos();
}
```